# Vox Populi needs 40 votes a day, limit is 30 votes

Tags: support, badges

If [you visit the badges page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/badges), you'll find out, that for the badge 'Vox Populi', which has been awarded 3 times, you need to have "Used the maximum 40 votes in a day".

Today I reached the daily vote limit of 30 votes. So it seems the vote limit was lowered after some time, or maybe the badges-page is a copy from SO, and the number has not been adapted.

- Question a) Which of it is it?
- Question b) Is it still possible to reach the badge, because it is bound to a value in the settings, which is 30 today?

Something needs to be fixed - either only the badges page, or badges page and the treshold to reach the vox-populi badge, or something else I didn't think of.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll notice that [suffrage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/badges/57/suffrage) is bronze badge awarded for using all *30* votes in one day.

The deal is that there are 10 "extra" votes if you are [voting enough on *questions*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/). I wasn't clear on [*when* you have to use them to have them qualify for the "extra"s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90726/2509), but it seems to require that you have cast 1 in 3 votes (so far this day?) for questions (so at least 10 of the first 30?) to be allowed to cast the spare ones.

Comment: I'm not sure about the numbers, since Justin says, that it is set in stone, when I reach the `N votes remaining` warning, which is normally 5 votes, so I expect, that if I'm above the threshold all the time, I get it at 35 votes, but if I have no vote on questions, I get it at 25 votes.

Comment: @userunknown For each question you vote on, you get an additional vote, up to 40.

Comment: my Vox Populi hasn't been awarded, after useing 40 votes twice already. `BUG`?